# Can you prove that $f(x) = 0$ for every linear functional $f$ implies $x=0$ in a normed space without using Hahn-Banach?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

In the context of another problem, I have to use the fact that if $f(x) = 0$ for all $f$, then $x=0$. I constructed my own proof of this using the Hahn-Banach theorem, which goes like this:

**Proof**: Assume that $x \neq 0$. Construct a functional $g$ in the following way: let $g(x) = 1$ and on $\text{span}(x)$ let $g$ be linear (this is well-defined on $\text{span}(x)$). By Hahn-Banach, $g$ can be continuously extended to the whole space, which contradicts the assumption that every functional is zero in $x$.

This is probably overkill for such a simple-looking statement, but I have no idea how to prove it in a more elementary way.

**Edit**:
I actually found a way to circumvent using Hahn-Banach (but not the axiom of choice). It goes like this:

**Proof**: Assume that $x \neq 0$. Let $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ be a basis of our vector space (where $I$ is some index set). Suppose that $x = \sum_{i \in I} x_i e_i$. Since $x \neq 0$, there exists an $x_i$ which is not zero, let's call its index $j$. Construct the following linear functional $g$: On $e_j$, let $g$ be 1, on every other basis vector, let $g$ be zero. In that case$$g(x) = g(\sum_{i \in I} x_i e_i) = \sum_{i \in I} x_i g(e_i) = x_j g(e_j) = x_j \neq 0 $$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: This indirectly uses Hahn-Banach too, but it's another approach. Use the power of the dual notion. Canonically, given $x$ in your normed space, its image in the bidual does the following. $xf = fx$, for any linear functional $f$. But $fx = 0$, always. So $xf = 0$ for all $f$, so $x$ acts as $0$, and the canonical bijection onto the image tells you that $x$ is $0$ in the normed space.

Comment: @PranavChinmay I believe you need Hahn-Banach to show that the canonical map $x\mapsto \hat{x}$ is injective.

Comment: You should put your assumptions into the body of your question, and I don't think "normed space" is what you have in mind. If you mean "Banach space", say so, please. The idea that there are "elementary" ways to prove things in Banach spaces is... erm... cute, btw. :)

Comment: @ProfessorVector No, I don't mean Banach space, I mean a general normed space, without assuming that it is complete. Thanks for the edit of the title btw

Comment: Whatever your assumptions are, put them *into the body of your question*. Especially the fact (if that's a fact) that you're speaking of *linear* functionals (I hope, it's certainly not true, otherwise).

Comment: @Stinking Bishop In the context of normed linear spaces, "functional" usually means continuous linear functional. Your example usually won't be continuuous.

Comment: I don't think this is an overkill at all!  Producing a continuous functional on a Banach space is not a walk in the park, and (set theorists, pease help me) I believe it is consistent with the axioms of set theory, with the axiom of choice removed, that there exists a Banach space without any continuous linear functionals at all!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ruy says in the comments, this is not a simple-looking statement at all. Without the Hahn-Banach theorem it's not clear that an arbitrary Banach space admits any nonzero continuous linear functionals, and in fact

1. The Hahn-Banach theorem is independent of ZF, and
2. Furthermore there are models of ZF containing Banach spaces with no nonzero continuous linear functionals (in other words, their continuous dual is trivial). See, for example, [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem/5477#5477), which describes a model of ZF in which $\ell^{\infty}/c_0$ (the Banach space of bounded sequences equipped with the sup norm, modulo the closed subspace of sequences converging to $0$) has trivial dual.